# how to use mqtt in react native or to use java script client in react native

Tags: react-native, mqtt

I needed mqtt client for react native, this one I am trying to use,
https://github.com/rh389/react-native-paho-mqtt

but when just write first line it give me 500 error in app,

```
import { Client, Message } from 'react-native-paho-mqtt';
```

I am new to react-native, can any help how we can use this, I downloaded using npm install.

Comment: Can you check the `package.json`, i've got it as `"react-native-paho-mqtt": "^0.1.1",`, also post your error here.

Comment: thanks @PritishVaidya, my mistake, I installed globally earlier, now i can in package.json. let me just try to do more work, I really needed your help I guess. thanks